# How do i validate user input that starts with 2 numbers?

Tags: python, validation, string-length

I have tried to validate some input for my homework. 
Requirements:

- starts with 34 / 37 and has 15 digits: `AMEX card`
- starts with 4 and has 16 digits: `VISA card`
- if card number with 15 digits but does not start with 34, 37, print:
  `You have entered an invalid Amex card numbers`
- if card number with 16 digits but does not start with 4, print: `You have entered an invalid Visa card numbers`
- Card numbers that are not 15 or 16 digits, print: `You have entered an invalid credit card number`
- Once the card number has been validated, your program shall display the card type (`Amex` or `Visa`) and the last 4 digits of the credit card number.

I have tried to do `len(number)` to find the number of digits from user input. However, I keep getting the error `"invalid syntax"`

```py
    number = int(input("Enter your credit card number :"))

    if len(number) = 16 and number.startswith(4):
        validity = "valid"
    if len(number) = 15 and number.startswith(34) and number.startswith(37):
        validity = "valid"
    else:
        validity = "invalid"
```

I cannot seem to get the correct outcome that I want.

This is how the program should run:

```
    Enter your credit card number : 432143214321432
    You have entered an invalid Amex card numbers
    Enter your credit card number : 3456345634563456
    You have entered an invalid Visa card numbers
    Enter your credit card number : 123
    You have entered an invalid credit card number
    Enter your credit card number : 4321432143214321
    You have a valid Visa card and the last 4 digit is 4321
```

Comment: Your first problem is that integers do not have a length so `len(number)` does not make sense. I would leave it as a string which does have a length

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator, you should use `==` to compare that two objects are equal

Comment: You do not need to convert it to `int` as all your checks are string based. Just remove the `int` part in `input` and change assignments ( = ) to comparison ( == ) operator, and you should be good.

Comment: If you'll read it as a string instead of an int: `int(input("Enter your credit card number :"))` (remove the `int` part), you'll be able to check the length and use string operations like `startswith`, but you'll have to pass it a string not an int, meaning: instead of `.startswith(4)` you should do: `.startswith('4')` and etc

Comment: As mentioned in the other comments, don't convert the input to an `int`. There's another reason, though. If the user entered `012345`, then converting to an `int` would give you `12345`, which is different to what the user entered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if len(number) = 16 and number.startswith(4):
```

- `len(number)`. Number does not have a len, so either convert number to a string here or don't convert it to an int in the first place
- `number.startswith(4):`. Same for this, ints do not have a startswith() method
- `==` is the comparison operator, not `=`

```
    number = input("Enter your credit card number :")

    if len(number) == 16 and number.startswith('4'):
        validity = "valid"
    if len(number) == 15 and number.startswith('34') or number.startswith('37'):
        validity = "valid"
    else:
        validity = "invalid"
```

If you need number as an int (unlikely for a credit card number) convert it with
`number = int(number)`

Answer (score 0):

it is easier to let it as a string then to convert it to an int in this Case. another Mistake is the "=" operator which is an assignment operator, if you want comparison you need to use double equal "==":

```
number =input("Enter your credit card number :")

if len(number) == 16 and number.startswith('4'): # this will get executed if the length equal 16 and the number starts with 4
    validity = "valid"
if len(number) == 15 and number.startswith('34') or number.startswith('37'):
    validity = "valid"
else:
    validity = "invalid"
```

Answer (score 0):

> This would be a simpler code for your problem. also '=' is an assignment operator and for comparisons use'==' always.

```
  number=input()

  if len(number)==15 and (number.startswith('34') or number.startswith('37')):
       print("Valid AMEX card")
  elif len(number)==16 and number.startswith('4'):
       print("valid Visa card")
  else:
       print("invalid card")
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend writing a function to validate your input using a flow of logic. The function should avoid using an else statement. The function should return if you match the correct input. If no input is matched return "invalid". In this way you don't need to try and validate all incorrect inputs.

Inside the function match/validate using regex, this is a good method as you can check digits and strings easily and quickly.

First we need to check that the input is 15 or 16 digits. We have 2 separate branches which match. In the first we match 15 digits in the second we match 16 digits.

In the 15 digit branch, it is required to check if the input start with 34 or 37 and return AMEX, or invalid AMEX. 
In the 16 digit branch, it is required to check if the input starts with 4 and return VISA, or invalid VISA.

The syntax `card_number[:2]` is using a slice of a string in python, you can read more about python strings it [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).

It is tempting to put and `else` in both 15 digit and 16 digit branches, however I always find it is easier to read when the check is explicit.

If we don't match any good card formats, the default is to return "invalid".

I recommend reading and familiarising yourself with regex as it is super powerful, and *can* be very fast. It is also supported in lots of languages, and operating systems.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

```
import re

def validate(card_number):
    # we convert the input to a string
    card_number = str(card_number)
    if re.match('^\d{15}$', card_number):
        if re.match('^(34|37)', card_number[:2]):
            # starts with 34 / 37 and has 15 digits: AMEX card
            return 'AMEX Card and end with %s' % card_number[-4:]
        if not re.match('34|37', card_number[:2]):
            # if card number with 15 digits but does not start with 34, 37, print: You have entered an invalid Amex card numbers
            return 'INVALID AMEX Card'
    if re.match('^\d{16}$', card_number):
        if re.match('^4', card_number[:1]):
            # starts with 4 and has 16 digits: VISA card
            return 'VISA Card and end with %s' % card_number[-4:]
        if not re.match('4', card_number[:1]):
            # if card number with 16 digits but does not start with 4, print: You have entered an invalid Visa card numbers
            return 'INVALID VISA Card'
    # Card numbers that are not 15 or 16 digits, print: You have entered an invalid credit card number
    return 'Invalid CC Number'
```

Here we can see the validate function working.

```
>>> validate('345634563456345')
'AMEX Card and end with 6345'
>>> validate(345634563456345)
'AMEX Card and end with 6345'
>>> validate('432143214321432')
'INVALID AMEX Card'
>>> validate('545634563456345')
'INVALID AMEX Card'
>>> validate('3456345634563456')
'INVALID VISA Card'
>>> validate('4321432143214320')
'VISA Card and end with 4320'
>>> validate('5556345634563456')
'INVALID VISA Card'
>>> validate('123')
'Invalid CC Number'
>>> validate('nothing')
'Invalid CC Number'
```

Comment: Using regular expressions for this seems like overkill.

Comment: @Wodin Agreed in this case regex is probably overkill. As this is a school assignment, learning regex is probably not a bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

- Use `==` to compare
- Don't convert the `input` to an `int`
- I put `try` and `exception` to make sure the user only enter int numbers

So, the updated code is:

```
number = input("Enter number your credit card number:\n")
def card(number):
    try:
        if len(number) == 16 and number.startswith('4'):
            print("Valid VISA")
        elif len(number) == 15 and number.startswith('34') or number.startswith('37'):
            print("Valid Amex")
        else:
            print("Invalid")
    except ValueError:
        print("Enter only numbers")
card(number)
```

Comment: If the user enters `0123456789012345`, then turning it into an int and then a string to compare the length will get `15` instead of `16`, so it will look like an "invalid Amex" card instead of an "invalid Visa" card.

Comment: It will print "Invalid" only since the number doesn't start with 4.

Comment: The requirement was "if card number with 16 digits but does not start with 4, print: You have entered an invalid Visa card numbers"

Comment: You're right. I see what's the problem; I don't need to use `str` and `int` to calculate `len` (I'm going to edit that). Now `0123456789012345` will have a length of 16. You can see that printing only "Invalid" was intentional since the beginning to keep the code simple and short.